# Is it possible to run resmon.exe (Resource Monitor) on Hyper-V Server 2016, and how if yes?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2016

I wanted to monitor a Hyper-V Server 2016 machine. While Task Manager is giving me some basic information, I wanted to dig deeper, in which Resource Monitor (resmon.exe) is doing just fine on graphical editions of Windows.

Unfortunately, Hyper-V Server 2016 doesn't seem to have resmon installed and even copying the executable from regular Windows machine doesn't help - the program just does nothing. Maybe it's enough to copy some additional files to have it running? Same thing happens on Hyper-V Server 2019.

I'm aware that it's possible to remotely monitor a machine using Performance Monitor, but this tool is quite different (based mainly on counters) and I need resmon's unique abilities like checking which files are being read and how fast or how much data is exchanged over the network with a specific host.

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching further for a solution, I found something that can work pretty well as a workaround. It's **NirSoft's FileActivityWatch** utility. While it doesn't show file transfer speeds and network operations, it shows what files are read, written and how many bytes, which fits my needs quite well.